# Regular expression to find unknown string and change case in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I want to find strings on a whole line that have a blank line above, but text on the following line.  Then I want the found string(s) to be upper-cased.  I will never know the names ahead of time. (and I am doing this in `Google Apps Script`).

Example text:

```
susan jones  
Good morning, children.  How are you today?

Susan jones is a 1st grade school teacher.  bob smith is a plumber.

bob smith  
Hello, Susan.  You are nice.
```

---

I want to uppercase all of the names of people speaking.  So the text will look like this:

```
SUSAN JONES  
Good morning, children.  How are you today?

Susan jones is a 1st grade school teacher.  Bob smith is a plumber.

BOB SMITH  
Hello, Susan.  You are nice.
```

Comment: ```^(\w+ \w+)\s*$``` for finding only name and surname , so replace it with uppercase, ```\U\1```. By finding this we assume that texts by user won't be two words only

Comment: Thank you!  Actually names can appear in any variation: Susan, Susan Jones, Doctor Susan Jones, Doctor Susan Jones Sr., etc.  I tried: `^((\w+ \w+)|(\w+)|(\w+ \w+ \w+)|(\w+ \w+ \w+ \w+))\s*$` which works until it hits a string with a period at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to grab lines with a preceeding blank line and text on the next you can use this:

```
[\n][\n]([^\n]+)[\n][^\n|\s]
```

However this will not work if there are no blank lines before the first name.
If using javascript you can simply provide a function to your replace method which returns the captured group ($1) in upper case.

But this doesn't sound like a very good approach to me. If people can have line breaks in their posts, then this will surely go wrong sooner or later.

I would also not recommend the other suggestion which assumes that all users have 2 names and that no one ever posts 2 words.

Consider this example:

```
susan jones  
Good morning, children.  How are you today?

Also BTW
Good evening too...

Susan jones is a 1st grade school teacher.  bob smith is a plumber.

bob smith  
Hello, Susan.  You are nice.
```

This would make the word "Also" upper case with both approaches.

You say you're getting all this as a single string? There is no other way for you to get this text with more information attached to it.

Of course if users can not have line breaks in their posts then this regex should work for you. But I still think it should be possible to find a better way to do this.

Comment: Awesome.  I ran this through regex101.com and it's also grabbing the "G" in "good morning", and "G" in "good evening, and "H" in "Hello".   Is there a way to avoid that?  Otherwise it works great.

Comment: It'll get highlighted because it's part of the match, but it is not part of the capturing group. Notice the match information on the right.

Comment: Excellent!  However, Google Apps script has trouble with this as their documentation for findText() states "A subset of the JavaScript regular expression features are not fully supported, such as **capture groups** and mode modifiers." Can this be accomplished without using a capture group?  Does that even make sense?

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this without capturing groups being available. Since you need to check if there is text on the next line. I would say capture groups are a pretty essential feature in regular expressions, surprised it's not supported.

Comment: As I understand it you use the javascript replace method (But a Google Apps Script version with less features for the regex). So provided it's still possible to provide a method as the replace argument, I would do that and split the string inside that function so you only make the name upper case. That's the best option I can think of without using capturing groups...

Comment: The reason this regex doesn't work in Google Docs is that they aren't text documents; it's a WYSIWYG editor that is showing individual paragraph elements (and others), so while it looks like all the text is continuous, and you can do regex searches on it, the particular patterns of `newlines` will not appear.